# PyQt5 and QtQuick

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

When I try to run the PyQt5 QtQuick example present in the folder PyQt5\examples\quick\tutorials\extending\chapter1-basics I get this error:

```
QQmlExpression: Expression file:///(...)/example.qml:17:15 depends on non-NOTIFYable properties:  
    PieChart::name  
class QWindowsEGLStaticContext *__cdecl QWindowsEGLStaticContext::create(void): Could not initialize egl display: error 12289  

QtQuick: failed to create OpenGL context
```

Do I have to configure something for running this example?

Comment: Do you have opengl installed? Did you use a standard pyqt install that includes qtopengl?

Comment: no i didn't install opengl. I used the Binary Packages from the riverbankcomputing.
Can you explain what I have to install to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install [DirectX Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=35), reboot and launch script again. It's needed for the PyQt QtQuick to work properly on Windows in some cases.

Comment: Incredible, it worked! I would never have thought this could be the issue, but seems like OpenGL is actually implemented on top of DirectX in MS Windows. But why was this missing... strange.