# WinPython with PyQt5

Tags: qt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm trying to get PyQt5 working with WinPython. PyQt5 comes with a readme file for installation, and I have unsuccessfully tried a few combinations of what I thought the first part of the readme tells me to do.

I have:

- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.1
- Qt 5.4
- PyQt-gpl-5.4

PyQt-gpl-5.4 is in the folder (only partially sure that this is where I should have put it)

```
C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.1\python-2.7.9.amd64\Lib\site-packages\PyQt-gpl-5.4
```

My current attempt at getting everything working is: I'm trying to run the configure.py file in PyQt-gpl-5.4, but when I do so I consistently get the following error:

```
Error: PyQt5 requires Qt v5.0 or later. You seem to be using v4.8.6.
Make sure the correct version of qmake is on your PATH.
```

What I think is the required version of qmake being referred to is in the folder

```
C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin
```

However, I have no idea how to fix the error by adding the qmake in this folder to PATH. My most recent attempt was to add the folder using Spyder's Tools->PYTHONPATH manager, but this made no difference. I also tried adding it using sys.path.append('C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin'), but this didn't work either. I have since removed the folder name from both of these locations.

How do I get PyQt5 working with WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.1, or I think equivalently, how to I get the configure.py file in the PyQt-gpl-5.4 folder to run?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want the source code (i.e. `PyQt-gpl-5.4`) in the site-packages folder, because that's where the compiled modules will end up. Instead, it should just go in a temporary folder whilst you compile it.

When you run `configure.py`, you **must** take care to use the executable for the specific python that you are targeting. I do not know anything about WinPython, but for a normal python installation this means doing something like this:

```
    C:\Python34\python configure.py
```

As a first step, before attempting to actually compile anything, it would be advisable to take at look at all the configuration options that are available, like this:

```
    C:\Python34\python configure.py --help
```

(There's also the [Installing PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html) section in the PyQt Docs).

This will tell you, for instance, that the simplest way to specify the Qt installation you are targeting would be something like this:

```
    C:\Python34\python configure.py --qmake C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin\qmake
```

**EDIT**:

Sorry, that last part is wrong: the `--qmake` option isn't available on Windows, so you have to add the directory containing the `qmake` executable to your `PATH`. This can be done with the following command:

```
    set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I read this, I tried it, but got the error: "no such option: --qmake". I looked in the configure.py file and found a line that says
    if sys.platform != 'win32': g.add_option("--qmake"...)
So apparently my platform is win32, even though my OS is 64-bit. I don't know anything about platforms, but does this make sense? Should it be win64 instead of win32? If so, is there a way I can manually tell the computer to use win64 as the platform when doing this instead of win32?
Thanks.

Comment: @user3558855. Sorry, I only looked at the help output in Linux, and missed the differences for Windows. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Great, thanks very much. That got me passed the qmake issue. I'm still getting an error though, "Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation. Try again using the --verbose flag to see more detail about the problem.", and when I use the verbose flag, " 'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command". I'm going to play around with it a bit more - the next thing I'm goint to try is to use Python 3 instead of 2 based on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846501/how-to-install-pyqt5-on-windows.