# How to get either Pyside or PyQt5 installed on Windows for 3.5.1?

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, pip, pyqt5

To clarify: This is separate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846501/how-to-install-pyqt5-on-windows) as it focuses on Python 3.5.1. So I installed the newest version of Python on my computer, 3.5.1 and noticed that among other things, one of the biggest changes is the fact that the default compiler has switched to VS2015. (I was also unsure whether to post this question under here or superuser, since it is issue with software, but at the same time the software is a development tools and I will likely need to compile that. Not the biggest deal, I am fine with trying to get old packages working and upgraded, however, as a result I have been without my favorite IDE Spyder because of it's reliance on PyQt5 or PySide. All the tutorials I have found suggest to go and install the PyQt5 binaries form Riverside, but alas they have not released any for newer versions of Python and unfortunately PySide is as dead as Nokia currently is. This is in mind, how can I easily install PyQt5 on my computer. I already have Qt5 installed and would like to avoid having to rebuild the entire Qt5 system from scratch. Are there any easy alternatives I am neglecting?

Comment: I'd simply wait a few more days/weeks if you can. PyQt 5.6 will soon be released, as a Python 3.5-compatible wheel on PyPI, and then it'll just be a `pip install PyQt` away.