# PyQt5 Installation

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I am new to the world of python and I was hoping you could help with my PyQt5 installation troubles.

I have downloaded PyQt5 (zip folder) for Windows and extracted onto my desktop.
Source: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5

As instructed in the read me file, I have also installed the latest SIP package (also extracted to the desktop) and I have run the configure.py in python 3.5 to receive the following error:

```
Error: Use the --qmake argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake.
```

Does anyone know why this may be? Or how I fix it and complete the install?

Additionally, I have watched a tutorial on YouTube... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBME1ZyHiP8
However when trying to run his code (shown below) I get the:

```
'ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

Is this linked to the install issues?

Code:
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtGui
    app = QtGui.QApplication (sys.argv)
    window = QtGui.Qwidget()
    window.setGeometry (50, 50, 800, 500)
    window.setWindowTitle("GIS Demonstration")
    window.show()

Am I missing something? All solutions welcome.

Thanks,
Jodie

Comment: Have you seen [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846501/how-to-install-pyqt5-on-windows?rq=1)

Comment: I have but note that the answer is for Python 3.3 not for Python 3.5 which was released in September 2015. Does this matter?

Comment: @Josephine. Do not try to use the zip file you downloaded. It only contains the source code, and you would need to build everything yourself, which can be quite complicated on windows. Instead, you should install the pre-compiled binaries using pip. To do this, open a command window, and run this command: `py -3 -m pip install pyqt5`.

Answer (score 0):

I install it with the cmd (shell):

> pip install pyqt5

this works for my

Comment: When I do this I get:
    'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: It would be good, if you put the path to pip in your environment variables.

Comment: @Josephine use `pip3 install pyqt5`