# Unable to install python packages due to enviroment error

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install PyQt `pip install pyqt5`, and it fails at the very end:
`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 2] Cannot find file: 'C:\\Python38\\Scripts\\pylupdate5.exe' -> 'C:\\Python38\\Scripts\\pylupdate5.exe.deleteme'`

Any ideas? PyQt documentation says nothing about this error, this one command should install it.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846501/how-to-install-pyqt5-on-windows#:~:text=%20Steps%20to%20install%20pyQt5%20%28with%20VS%202012%29,Command%20Prompt.%207%20Execute%20these%20commands%3A%20More%20

Comment: Ok, so the answer is don't use command because it doesn't work. I get a lot of warnings even while installing suggested vs code packages, but i suppose this is how python (doesn't) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be the anti-virus or firewall. Disable it and try again.

Comment: Had to launch cmd in admin mode. VSCode terminal was not enough.